# undefined variable or function

Tags: matlab

I have created a function in MATLAB & have saved it as an m file. When I run my function, it's fine. However using the Windows 7 scheduler it goes to run my function and gives the error message `'Undefined variable 'myMethod' or function 'myMethod.m'`.

When I run the `which('myMethod.m')` it returns the correct folder so not sure what this error message is about?

The `pwd` method returns the correct address of where my function is too, `C:\SomeFolder\MATLAB\Me`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably its simply not finding the function because it is not on the path.
Assuming you can run builtin functions via the scheduler, try something like this:

```
p = path
save p
% save c:\ p
```

In case you cannot even find the saved file, use the last line instead.

Match the path with your files location and presumably the path does not contain the folder which holds your file.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for the reply. Just found that in the Edit Action section of the windows scheduler that the command -r myFunction should not have the .m file extension. Bit strange but now runs

Comment: @mHelpMe You saved my mental sanity. THANKS